# Its my first time trying to create a website , I got an error Please help

Tags: functions, fatal-error

I was updating wordpress, throught it was done. I downloaded Astra ... I am new to all this. Thank you for your help

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function **is_customize_preview()** in /home/content/21/7421521/html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/customizer/class-astra-customizer.php on line 70

Comment: Disable the plugin.  The error message is telling you the astra customizer is looking for a function that does not exist.  Either the plugin did not install correctly or it is flawed.  Either way, deactivating it will get your site up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling WordPress from scratch. Replace everything **except** your `wp-config.php` file, `.htaccess` file, `nginx.conf` file, and `wp-contents/` directory.

This error is calling a missing function that's a part of WordPress core since 4.0.0.